# PC monitor adapter amperage/voltage

Tags: display, adapter, voltage

I am new here. I just got a PC monitor with an adapter that doesn't belong to it. The monitor requires a 19V 2.6A power source but the one I was given is 15V and 5A. It works just fine, but I would like to know if this could in any way, shape or form damage my computer or the monitor itself? The monitor in question is a CMV CT-726D.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much, guys, I really appreciate your time and effort. If I get 19v and 1.58a, is that workable? I can't find any 19v 2.6a anywhere, that's the closest I found and it's a laptop charger. You think it'll work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to damage it.  You can have more amps all you want, but not significantly more or less volts. 19.6v vs 15v is a big difference.  Most computer things are design for + or - 5%.  It has no impact on the computer.  I would fine a new power brick ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, low voltage electronics will be stepping that down to much lower voltages anyway, but you could be damaging the internal power supply.

The important parts are,

19v @ 2.6A = ~50W -> what the monitor can be expected to draw
15v @ 5.0A = ~75W -> power available

Internally, these voltages are being stepped down to 12v, 5v, 3.3v, and lower.

The issue that may be faced is that if something internally requires 12v, the power supply need to step that down, and may burn off a few volts to get there. With the 19v supply, that would not be an issue, with the 15v supply some things may be undervolted and could overheat by drawing too much current.